# how to know whether input is a number or not?

Tags: c, gcc

I have a problem.

My program needs to check whether the input is a number or anything else,in C.I searched and found that `isdigit(int)` is a function provided for this..but it only checks `48<=ASCII<=57` .

But what if i have to check for numbers only ? Is there any function like `isInteger()`,`isReal()`,`isFloat()` etc? and if not then how can i check for them?

In case of `isdigit()` too, I am getting a problem:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
int main(){
    int i = 1;
    printf("%d",isdigit(i));
    return 0;
}
```

it outputs `0` ,i do not understand ,it should be a non zero value ...

Comment: `isdigit` operates on character codes. The character code `1` does not appear to be a digit in your encoding. Try with `'1'` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the input is a string, use [`strtol()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html) and/or [`strtod()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtod.html).

Example

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char input[1000];
    // get input, don't forget to check for errors
    if (fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in input\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char *err;
    errno = 0;
    long x = strtol(input, &err, 10);
    if (errno || *err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "input is not an integer in the range for `long`.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    errno = 0;
    double y = strtod(input, &err);
    if (errno || *err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "input is not a correct double.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // use x and y as needed

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Read the documentation of [isdigit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isdigit.3.html). It applies to *characters*, not *numbers*. So `isdigit('2')`  should be true (non-zero). As [answered by pmg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25217253/841108) see also [strtol(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html)...

<sup>If you wanted to test digits of [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) or Unicode it is much more complex. Use a library function, e.g. [g_unichar_is_digit](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Unicode-Manipulation.html#g-unichar-isdigit) from Glib for Unicode.</sup>

You might make a fundamental mistake. A [number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number) is not made of digits. It is *represented* or *written* with digits. So *two*, 2 (decimal), II (roman notation), `0b10` or 10 (binary), *deux* (French), `1+1` (arithmetic expression), 二 (Chinese) .... all represent the same number (which is the successor of one), but only the second representation -decimal `2`-  has one digit.

Comment: It seems that you still don't grasp the difference between a number and a digit. Go to a library, read some philosophical or mathematical book. I enjoyed a lot the *Theorie des Ensembles* ("Set Theory") of Bourbaki -I've read the two-hundred pages French original edition. IIRC, it has a sentence like "the following expression" ... some complex math glyphs ... can b expended to an expression of many thousands signs, but it represent "two" (or "one", I forgot which).

Answer (score 2):

From [isdigit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/) man page:

> Check if character is decimal digit

So you can see that this function is applied to characters. Its return value should be non - zero.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
bool checkNumber(const char *str) 
{
    while(*str != '\0')
    {
        if(*str < '0' || *str > '9')
            return false;
        str++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It works, but is tricky. Better use `isdigit` or just `strtol`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch:- Indeed. You suggested isDigit() which I would go with and was about to answer but tried to go different. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this man.....

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
char a;
printf("enter any int\n");
scanf("%c",&a);
if(isdigit(a))
{
    printf("input was a number");
}
else
    printf("input wasnt a number");
return 0;
}
```